# Searching .pdf's for unique words

Tags: macos, automator

I would like to be able to search a selected .pdf(s) for 20 unique words on demand.  I get a different .pdf file each month and would like to automate search so that I do not have to type in 20 different words each time.

For example:  I need to know if the selected .pdf contains the words, ship, otus, lebanon, enterprise, etc...  Then display which word(s) are found in the search.

I have tried this multiple times in Automator but cannot get it to work.

Can anyone show me the steps to complete this in automator?

EDIT:  SO I have been trying....  I have done this

[image: another try pic]

But it does not accomplish what I am trying to do.  First, I cannot figure out how to get the found words to display.  2nd, I am selecting a .pdf to run, but results show multiple .pdf's....

So i run this:

use framework "Foundation"
use framework "PDFKit"
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite or later
use scripting additions

property PDFDocument : a reference to current application's PDFDocument
property NSArray : a reference to current application's NSArray
property NSCharacterSet : a reference to current application's NSCharacterSet
property NSURL : a reference to current application's NSURL

property NSString : a reference to current application's NSString
property NSPredicate : a reference to current application's NSPredicate
property NSUTF8StringEncoding : a reference to current application's NSUTF8StringEncoding

on run {input, parameters}

```
set searchFile to POSIX path of (item 1 of input) as text
# force each of the PDFs to be a POSIX path instead of the Finder's HFS format
set pdfs to (NSArray's arrayWithArray:(rest of input as list))'s allObjects()'s valueForKey:"path"

# what we use to clean up extraneous characters in the pdf text
set alnum to (NSCharacterSet's alphanumericCharacterSet)'s mutableCopy()
set nopunct to NSCharacterSet's punctuationCharacterSet
alnum's formUnionWithCharacterSet:nopunct
alnum's invertedSet()

# get the search words into their array
set searchFile to (NSString's alloc()'s initWithContentsOfFile:searchFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding |error|:0)
set searchWords to NSArray's arrayWithArray:(searchFile's componentsSeparatedByString:linefeed)

repeat with aPDF in pdfs
    # make specific output text file for each PDF
    set OUTFILE to (NSString's stringWithString:aPDF)'s stringByDeletingPathExtension()'s mutableCopy()
    (OUTFILE's appendString:"_matched.txt")
    set pdfName to aPDF's lastPathComponent() as text
    
    # get all of the words in the current PDF document into a cleaned up array
    set pdf to (PDFDocument's alloc()'s initWithURL:(NSURL's fileURLWithPath:aPDF))
    set pdfText to (pdf's selectionForEntireDocument())'s |string|() as text
    set mytext to ((NSString's stringWithString:(my split_words(pdfText)))'s stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:alnum)
    set pdfWords to (mytext's componentsSeparatedByString:linefeed)'s mutableCopy()
    
    # match words from searchFile to the PDF word array
    set pred to (NSPredicate's predicateWithFormat:"SELF IN[c] %@" argumentArray:pdfWords)
    set matchedWords to (searchWords's filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred)'s mutableCopy()
    
    if not ((count of matchedWords) = 0) is true then
        set outStr to (matchedWords's componentsJoinedByString:linefeed)
        (outStr's writeToFile:OUTFILE atomically:true)
    else
        display dialog "No words matched those in the current PDF: " & pdfName & return & "Skipping to next PDF it available." with title "Processing Notice" giving up after 5
        log "skipping"
    end if
    pdfWords's removeAllObjects()
    matchedWords's removeAllObjects()
    set pdfText to ""
    set mytext to ""
end repeat
return
```

end run

on split_words(astr)
return (do shell script "/bin/zsh -s <<'EOF' - " & astr's quoted form & "
#!/bin/zsh
setopt shwordsplit

## clobber these characters while splitting out words

typeset -a words=( ${(f)${1}//[.,;:!?]} )
print -l ${words}
EOF")
end split_words

And get this error:

[image: error 3]

Any help as to why?  I did not write it, but added it from some help someone wrote for me.  They say it works for them, but i cant get it to work.

So I got a lot of hep from Apple Community member who used Cocoa-AppleScript and GOT IT TO WORK!  I create .txt name search file and run the script and its output is a .txt file with names, if found, and on what page(s).  Here is an example of output after searching for these names:

[image: output]

I do not have permission yet to post his code.

Comment: Do matching PDFs need to contain at least one of these words or all of them? Are the words always the same? What do you want to with the matching PDFs (e.g. do they need to be printed, moved to a different folder, ...)?

Comment: I realized I didnt have enough info.  Sorry.  I am looking for the same words each time.  I need to know if the .pdf contains any of the words and to display which words found.  If word(s) are found, I can then go do a manual search to see where in the document it is found.

Comment: Unless you search for each word individually I don't see a way to see the found words via Automator. Installing `pdfgrep` via Homebrew combined with some shell scripting might work.

Comment: The action searches on the Desktop (in your case), it doesn't seem to accept files as input.

Comment: as a try workaround, I have cut and pasted "enterprise | otus | calhoun" , as 3 search terms Into the search bar of an opened .pdf in preview.  It does highlight the results ...  Now if could automate it and display using Automator...

Comment: when I run it, I get a pop-up which starts at the desktop and allows me to select file(s) from there.  Which is what I do.  Unless, its ignoring my selection and checking the entire desktop....

Comment: You did read the first few line of the search action? It‘s rather clear what it does :-)

Comment: The search action starts at the „Search PDF“‚Titel. It clearly says that it will search for PDF within the folder your set in the dropdown.

Comment: so can I take the output from what I select at the top, give it a variable name then replace Desktop with the variable name?